# Exception in thread

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy trabajando con java pero se me presenta este error, no se si porque estoy usando una librería

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`

Comment: Ese error ocurre porque estás usando una versión del JDK reciente y tienes puesto para que compile a una versión antigua que no es compatible. Por favor, pon el error completo para más detalles. ¿A qué versión de java estás compilando?

Comment: como verifico que versión esta compilando, uso netbens 13,Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.